look for best solution for deploy two web apps in tomcat 10
I have a problem when I try to deploy two apps in tomcat10, both are spring boot application, I package them into war file. what I want to achieve is: two web apps deployed in one tomcat, and a nginx will direct the request to one app according to its domain name, e.g: http://example.com will point to: app1(maybe: http://localhost:8080/app1), and http://bbs.example.com will goto app2(http://localhost:8080/app2). So below is my configuration:

I put two wars into tomcat/webapps, then each app can be accessed with context path. (/app1 or /app2)
I config nginx as below:

 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/app1/;
        .....
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name bbs.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/app2/;
        ...
    }
}

Now, if I visit each domain in web browser, http://example.com or http://bbs.example.com, both can work well.
But when I access tomcat directly: http://localhost:8080/app1, the static resource or links in the page don't have app1 context path(e.g <img src="/static/imgs/img1.jpg"/>), so the page css/js/image cannot access. Of course I can modify the pages, add context path(app1) in the page, but when I added the code in the pages, the domain request through Nginx will have similar problem: the page will have context path(all links in pages prefixed with 'app1'), they cannot be access via domain.
So you see I am in an awkward situation: if I add context path in the pages, domain request page has problem, if I don't add context path, then the localhost request has the same resource load problem.
I think there should be a good solution for my problem, So do you know what is the right solution for this. Thanks!

Check the Defining Tomcat context paths article, maybe it can be helpful.

@IvanShatsky, thank you, this is a very good article about how to config context on apps. But it didn't mention: when config the application with context 'app1', do I need add 'app1' prefix before all the links in the pages, as when we write page code, generally we will not add context name before the img/css/js links, view page source in browser, the links in the page is like this: "/api/articles"(no context, so cannot access). And because I have two apps, I cannot deploy apps in Root filder. Is there an option to handle this problem?

Can't you make your links looking like ./css/style.css instead of /css/style.css? This should make your assets available both under domain root and under any context prefix.

@IvanShatsky, thank you.  Yes, I think the relative path can resolve the problem, but I prefer to use absolute path, because there are so many pages, I need carefully to specify the relative path, also maybe some of files will be refactor to change their path, I also need to check whether need change the css/js file path. So if I prefer to use absolute path.
